# python Google Maps API Error G_GEO_UNKNOWN_ADDRESS

Tags: maps

```
from googlemaps import GoogleMaps,GoogleMapsError

gmaps = GoogleMaps()
address = "5555 Car Country Drive Carlsbad CA 92008"
result = gmaps.geocode(address)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yogesh/workspace/Simple/maps_error.py", line 10, in 
    result = gmaps.geocode(address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/googlemaps.py", line 262, in geocode
    raise GoogleMapsError(status_code, url, response)
googlemaps.GoogleMapsError: Error 602: G_GEO_UNKNOWN_ADDRESS

Answer (score 0):

remove the zipcode. googlemaps should be able to find the latlng values without it.

this is what I got:

```
gmaps.address_to_latlng('5555 Car Country Drive Carlsbad CA')
(33.1283128, -117.3218825)
```